# Sort a binary file with qsort

Tags: c

EDIT 3

THE FILE CONTAINS BYTES - I guess I have to sort the bytes, the task doesn't say more - it says that I pass an argument - the name of a binary file that contains bytes - that's it. And I am trying to work with low-level funcs.

I am trying to sort a binary file using qsort but I got stuck - I dont know how to write the content of a file to a buffer so I could pass it to qsort

What I have done:

```
int main(int argc, char*argv[]){
        int fd1;
        if((fd1=open(argv[1], O_RDONLY))==-1){
                printf("Error occurred while opening the file");
                exit(-1);
        }

        int size;
        char c;
        while(read(fd1, &c, 1)){
                size=size+1;
        }

        size=size+1;
        close(fd1);

        fd1=open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
        if(fd1==-1){
                printf("Error occured while opening the file");
        }

        char*buffer;
        buffer=malloc(size);
        setbuf(fd1, buffer);

        //EDIT I TRIED THIS AND IT STILL DOES NOT WORK
        int i=0;
        while(read(fd1, &c, 1)){
            buffer[i]=c;
            i++;
        }

        for(int i=0; i<size;i++){
            printf("lele %s", buffer[i]);
        }


        //EDIT 2: after making buffer[i]=c I get this error Segmentation fault

}
```

SetBuf does not work this way.. How to make it work? Also, I am trying to use func like open, close, read, write, etc.

Comment: What is `setbuf`?  It isn't defined here.

Comment: Just "sorting" a file doesn't make sense. Are you supposed to sort the bytes? Does the file contain some sort of data in the form of records (basically structures) that needs to be sorted? Why are you using the low-level `open`/`close`/`read` functions? What is your actual assignment/exercise?

Comment: What does it mean - to sort a binary file? Sort it's bytes? If so, then the most appropriate sorting method would be counting sort.

Comment: Yes, i wanna sort a binary file.

Comment: As for what I believe your problem might be, there are other ways to figure out the size of an opened file ([`fstat`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fstat.html) comes to mind). Then you can allocate the full (and *exact*!) size of the file, and read it all in one go. And you need to actually *read* it (unless you want to memory map it).

Comment: @Vanessa what does that **mean** ?? It may be clear in your mind, but we're not mind readers. We don't know what is *in* your file, how it is laid out, how "items" in your file compare to one another, etc..

Comment: I guess sorting doesn't matter here. What OP is trying to do is "write the content of a file to a buffer". We like solving small specific problems here, and we like also having context. So here, this question has both.

Comment: `&c` is a *pointer* to the variable `c`.

Comment: The file is just a binary file 

Lets say something like this

00000000: 4c6f 7265 6d20 6970 7375 6d20 646f 6c6f Lorem ipsum dolo
00000010: 7220 7369 7420 616d 6574 2c20 636f 6e73 r sit amet, cons
00000020: 6563 7465 7475 7220 6164 6970 6973 6369 ectetur adipisci
00000030: 6e67 2065 6c69 742c 2073 6564 2064 6f20 ng elit, sed do

Comment: That looks more like a *text* file.

Comment: Details belong properly formatted [in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70945175/edit), *please*.

Comment: And *please* take some time to read (or refresh) [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Show the (initial, or complete if the file is small enough) contents of the file in the question itself. And show us the expected output of your program.

Comment: I have edited the question.

Comment: `mmap()` it to load the file in memory and sort that space?

Comment: You never initialized `size`.  `int size; size = size + 1` is undefined behavior.

Comment: your malloc almost certainly failed cos size not initialized. Check it

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm for reading a file into a buffer is good:

1. Open the file
2. Count bytes in file
3. Close the file
4. Allocate the buffer
5. Open the file
6. Read the file
7. Close the file

A bit inefficient, because you read the file twice, but that's fine. You just have to implement it properly; any small mistake will make it look like it doesn't work. Use a debugger to check each step.

Here is my try. I didn't debug, to not deny you the "fun" of debugging. I put comments instead.

```
int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
    // 1. Open the file
    int fd1;
    if((fd1=open(argv[1], O_RDONLY))==-1){
        printf("Error occurred while opening the file");
        exit(-1);
    }

    // 2. Count bytes in file
    int size = 0;
    char c;
    while(read(fd1, &c, 1))
        size=size+1;
    // To check that this part is good, print the size here!

    // 3. Close the file
    close(fd1);

    // Allocate the buffer
    char *buffer;
    buffer = malloc(size);
    // Might want to print the buffer here, to make sure it's not NULL

    // 5. Open the file
    fd1=open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
    if(fd1==-1){
        printf("Error occurred while opening the file");
    }

    // 6. Read the file
    for (int index = 0; index < size; ++index)
        read(fd1, &buffer[index], 1);
    // Might want to print what "read" returns in each iteration, to make sure it's successful

    // 7. Close the file
    close(fd1);
}
```

---

As noted by Eric Postpischil, the algorithm is actually not good.

> The size of the file at one time does not guarantee the size at another time.

If you want to do that correctly, you must read the file only once. This will make the allocation harder: you cannot calculate the required buffer size, so you have to "guess" an initial size and use `realloc`.

However, in this small example, this is clearly not the requirement - you can probably ignore the possibility of the file changing asynchronously.

---

There is another possible problem - I/O error on the file when you read it the second time. This is easy to check, so maybe you should add it.

Comment: Re “Your algorithm for reading a file into a buffer is good:”: No, it is not. The size of the file at one time does not guarantee the size at another time. A program must be prepared for the end of the file to come at any point. After allocating some initial buffer, it ought to read to fill that buffer, and, if the end of file has not been reached, reallocate the buffer to be longer and repeat. And, while reading, it should test the return value of `read` in case less was read than expected.